# How to align three icons to the right of the page headline

Tags: html, angularjs, css, angular

I have the current situation:

[image]

Relevant code:

```
<md-toolbar color="primary" class="main-toolbar">
  <div fx-layout="row" fx-flex fx-layout-align="space-between">
    <span  class="page-headline">
      <img class="logo" src="./logo.png"/>club
    </span>
    <button md-icon-button class="main_menu_button1" (click)="dinnerClicked()">
      <md-icon>local_pizza</md-icon>
    </button>
    <button md-icon-button class="main_menu_button2" (click)="notificationsClicked()">
      <md-icon>notifications</md-icon>
    </button>
    <button md-icon-button class="main_menu_button3" (click)="eventsClicked()">
      <md-icon>event_note</md-icon>
    </button>
  </div>
</md-toolbar>
```

I just want the 3 icons to be adjacent closely to each other and align to the right. If I change `fx-layout-align` to `fx-layout-align-xs`, I get almost what I want:

[image]

But to the left instead of to the right...

I have tried many CSS configurations but none worked for me, is there any easy way to acheive this? Many thanks.

Comment: create jsfiddle for it.

Comment: you want the `justify-content: flex-start` css property, see here for more information: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/. Also my advice would be not to define this in your HTML but in CSS!

Comment: could you  try adding: `fx-layout-align="start"` as shown here: https://github.com/angular/flex-layout#api-overview

Comment: @JoelHarkes that produces the second output I have shown (correct but to the left inside of to the right)

Comment: then use `end` instead of `start` ? And if you want the buttons in different order you should change: `flex-direction: row-reverse`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using this plugin: https://github.com/angular/flex-layout#api-overview

i suggest:

```
<md-toolbar color="primary" class="main-toolbar">
  <div fx-layout="row" fx-flex fx-layout-align="end" >
    ...
  </div>
</md-toolbar>
```

Comment: This partly works. It **correctly** adjusts the icons like I wanted. But what it also does is move all the content of the headline to the right. I need just the icons to move. Tried to create another div but it messes up the content as well as it creates 2 "levels"...

Comment: what 'other content' is moved? is it also part of the flex box? Just changing these css properties shouldn't change the layout outside of the flexbox. Otherwise setting a fixed size might work?

Comment: The logo and "club" - `<img class="logo" src="./logo.png"/>club` inside the `span`

Comment: managed to fix it by specifying `<span  class="page-headline" fx-flex fx-layout-align="start">` . Thanks!

Comment: ah i see, wrap/seperate it in another flex box with:  `justify-content: space-between`

Answer (score 0):

Just add below code in your css:

```
<style>
.main_menu_button1,.main_menu_button2,.main_menu_button3
{
    float:right;
}
</style>
```

Comment: it is already floating as you can see in the first image, and by the fx-flex notations im pretty sure he uses a css flexbox layout

Comment: @JoelHarkes - Providing a fixed width for buttons might solve this if it still remains same.